# ViewDidLoad does not get called

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing an app for iPhone and iPad. The app has a TabBar to switch between ViewControllers. I know that when the app is developed for both devices all I have to do is create the Storyboard items again for iPad and just connect the properties with the ViewControllers that I already have i.e FirstViewController is the same for the iPhone and iPad app.

In the iPhone app there are three tabs but because iPad's screen size is bigger I would like to have two tabs for the iPad version. So I would like to merge SecondViewController and ThirdViewController for the iPad app. So I decided to subclass `UIViewController`and called it MyViewController. Inside MyViewController goes the code of `SecondViewController` and `ThridViewController`.

In the simulator I can see the background image and the Storyboard items of the `MyViewController`'s view. The problem is that `viewDidLoad` method doesn't get called on `MyViewController` class (I have a NSLog statement right after `[super viewDidLoad]`). I checked that in my storyboard in Idendity Inspector the class is `MyViewController`. Also tried to create a completely new ViewController with a new subclass but also for that new ViewController the method `viewDidLoad` method is not getting called.

Comment: Sorry about the stupid question, found the answer myself. If anyone wonders it was because when I ran the app I did it with iPhone Simulator then in the Hardware menu changed the device to iPad. But when I set the simulator to iPad Simulator and then ran the app then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tab bar controllers do not release **controller-A** when you move to **controller-B** and vice versa.They are allocated once and hence you don't see viewDidLoad when the tabs are shuffled.

You might have to check `viewWillAppear` method to see it the viewControllers are called or not!

Comment: I don't mean shuffling between tabs, I mean the first time I click the tab bar and MyViewController is loaded the `viewDidLoad` method isn't called. I know it is called only once.

Comment: Share your MyViewController code where you added SecondViewController & ThridViewController - That may be of some help to take it forward.

Comment: Actually I found the soultion and posted it in the comments. But the way I added the code to `MyViewController` was just copy-paste. I just needed a ViewController class for iPad version that contained the same code as `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController` in iPhone version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use these life cycle events:

Responding to View Events

```
– viewWillAppear:
– viewDidAppear:
– viewWillDisappear:
– viewDidDisappear:
– viewWillLayoutSubviews
– viewDidLayoutSubviews

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

viewDidAppear will be called when your view visible again